# how to do a split-view like application in iphone

Tags: iphone, nssplitview

Is there any way for implementing popovers and split-view in iphone application?.I saw a bible app OliveTree Bible reader,In this app they use the pop overs like feature and split-view like view display.I know split-view is only for ipad ,but how can i achieve these features in iphone app like the OliveTree Bible app.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should write the necessary code yourself. A split view is just two view on the screen. `addSubview:` should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use [WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover)